# Test if Button Text has changed

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcuitest

I have a button whose text changes based on certain criteria. I want to test this functionality with `XCUITest` but I can't seem to be able to access the text on the button.

I have tried

```
button.staticTexts
button.value
button.title
elementsQuery.buttons["My Button"] //This uses the accessibility label
```

How can I access the text?

Comment: Are you sure that `button` exists? Did you try `button.label`?

Comment: @lagoman I am sure. I did try the label but it also seems to be the accessibility label

Comment: Do you get error when trying to call `.value` or `.title` on `button` object? Do you know exact number of buttons on page (and do number of buttons change when text changes)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but try this:

```
let app = XCUIApplication();
let buttonText = app.otherElements["My Button"].staticTexts;
```

If this doesn't work let me know. Currently working on iOS XCUITests myself